# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED While Running Server on Other Laptop

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I can host a server on my laptop and it will run fine, but on other computers I get the error:

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8000);

app.use(express.static('public'));

console.log('Sever runnning');

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);
```

It works fine on my computer, but fails elsewhere.

Comment: You need to actually expose the port on your computer's firewall.  It won't just work natively.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Depends on your OS.  I'd suggest looking at SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

your local server working on your machine,app is running fine but on other laptop app is not running right? so on other laptop give your network IP then see the result.

Comment: I'm running the website on a LAN, and the other computers are connection to EXAMPLEIP:8000.

Comment: the network ip look like 192.168.0.4 and add your port here ,hop it will be work